# Prove linear independence and spans with linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose that $V,W$ are vector spaces over $\Bbb{F}$ and that $T : V → W$ is a
linear transformation.

(a) Suppose that $T$ is one-to-one, and that $\{v_1, · · · , v_n\}$ is linearly independent in $V$ . Prove that $\{T (v_1), · · · , T (v_n)\}$ is linearly independent in $W$.

(b) Suppose that $T$ maps $V$ onto $W$, and that $\{v_1,··· ,v_n\}$ spans $V$. Prove that $\{T(v_1),··· ,T(v_n)\}$ spans $W$.

I have got no clue as to what properties I should use to prove both a and b.

Comment: For 1 note that T is one to one is equivalent to T is non singular,

Comment: Write down what the definition of linearly independent / spans say about the $T(v_i)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me prepend this by saying that you should only look at a little bit of the solution of each to help you along, and see if you can figure out the rest for your own pedagogical value.

For (a):

To prove a set of vectors $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ is linearly independent, we need to show that
$$ c_1 a_1 + \cdots + c_n a_n = 0 \implies c_1 = \cdots = c_n = 0$$
Now we already know that
$$ c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n = 0 \implies c_1 = \cdots = c_n = 0$$
because $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are linearly independent.
Now, suppose
$$ c_1T(v_1) + \cdots + c_nT(v_n) = 0.$$
Then,
$$ T(c_1v_1) + \cdots T(c_nv_n) = 0$$ by linearity and
$$T(c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n) = 0$$ again by linearity. Finally, since $T$ is one-to-one, we know that its kernel is $\{ 0 \}$, so
$$c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n = 0.$$
But this means $c_1 = \cdots = c_n = 0$ which is what we needed to show.

For (b):
Pick $w \in W$. Then because $T$ is onto, there is $v \in V$ such that $T(v) = w$. But $v = c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n$. Then
$$T(v) = T(c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n).$$
Try to figure out the rest from here using a technique from (a).

Comment: If you really need more help for (b), let me know and I'll try to help you along in the comments to this answer.