# Injective and surjective linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone help with those two statements? My proofs were exactly the ones states below, but I can't see what's wrong with them..

[image]

Comment: @zipirovich ???

Comment: These proofs are backwards. For the first one, one must start with scalars $a_i$ such that $\sum a_i T(v_i) = 0$, not $\sum a_i v_i = 0$. For the second one, one must start with an arbitrary $w \in W$ and find the scalars $a_i$ such that $w = \sum a_i T(v_i)$, not start with some $v$ and let $w = T(v)$; what if $T = 0$??

Answer (score 2):

For problem 1, the proof never uses injectiveness of $T$, so it must be wrong (repeat the proof with the non-injective map $T=0$ to reach an absurd conclusion).

A correct proof that $(T(v_1), ..., T(v_n))$ is linearly independent should use the definition of linearly independent.  So it should start out:

"Suppose $a_1 T(v_1) + a_2 T(v_2) + ... + a_n T(v_n) = 0$ for some scalars $a_1, ..., a_n$.  We want to show that $a_i=0$ for all $i$."

Your proof starts out wrong: The way you start, it looks like you are trying to prove $(v_1, ..., v_n)$ are linearly independent (but you are *given* that fact, no need to prove it).

Specifically, your proof starts out assuming that $a_1v_1 + ... + a_n v_n =0$ for some scalars $a_1, ..., a_n$.  So what?  We immediately conclude that those scalars are all 0 from linear independence of $(v_1, ..., v_n)$.  But that says nothing about linear independence of $(T(v_1), ..., T(v_n))$.  Proceeding to the next (true) equation $a_1T(v_1)+...+a_nT(v_n)=0$ is useless since we have already established that all the $a_i$ are zero (which is why this equation is true but useless).  You might as well take any vectors $x_1, ..., x_n$ and (correctly) conclude that $a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n=0$ (simply because we already know all $a_i=0$). This is true but clearly does not establish linear independence of $(x_1, ..., x_n)$.

---

For problem 2 of showing $\{L(v_1), ..., L(v_n)\}$ span $W$:

Put the following out-of-order sentences together, and fill in the remaining portion of each sentence as appropriate (you can write the full proof with the correct order and completed sentences in your answer on this page):

a) $L$ is surjective, which means that for our particular $w \in W$, there is a $v \in V$ such that…

b) By linearity of the function $L$ we have…

c) Taking $L(\cdot)$ of both sides gives...

d) Fix $w \in W$.

e) To prove $\{L(v_1), ..., L(v_n)\}$ span $W$, we want to show there are scalars $\lambda_1, …, \lambda_n$ such that…

f) $\{v_1, …, v_n\}$ spans $V$, which means for our particular $v \in V$, there are scalars $\lambda_1, …, \lambda_n$ such that…

g) We have now proven what we wanted to prove.

Comment: This is really helpful! What about the surjectivity proof?

Comment: For that second one (which I just now read), it again starts backwards.  You should start out with a particular $w \in W$ (i.e., start your proof "Fix $w \in W$").  Then show you can form $w$ by a linear combination of $T(v_i)$.  The existing proof seems to start by picking a linear combination of $T(v_i)$ then randomly saying this leads to some $w$, it leaves open the question of whether you can get to every element of $W$ this way.

Comment: Could you please write it out? I don't know how to go from $w\in W$ to show that it is a linear comb of $T(v_i)$ without using $T(\lambda_1 v_1+\cdots+\lambda_n v_n)=w$.. Also, is the answer in this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236748/prove-linear-independence-and-spans-with-linear-maps) wrong..?

Comment: Also, that second proof never uses the (required) assumption that $T$ is surjective, so that is another way to see it is wrong.  (again, what if $T(v)=0$ for all $v$?)  I think you have the ability to work out the answer yourself, just start the correct way.  If you come to a place where you cannot think about waht to do next, ask "have I used all the assumptions I am given?" (i.e., "have I used surjectiveness of $T$?") You can answer your own question for this if you like.

Comment: Well, that answer in the link you give spells out the correct proof of both of these things (assuming "onto" means the same thing as "surjective"). It might still be helpful to do your own proof of part 2 and fill in any blanks or explanations for the proof given there. [that proof leaves out explaining why $v=c_1 v_1 + ... + c_nv_n$ is true for some scalars $c_i$, and it also leaves out a simple final step].

Comment: see my answer, I am getting frustated because I don't understand the surjectivity proof..

Comment: See my edited answer with "arrange these sentences in correct order" hints on the second proof.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is arguing backwards: it assumes that the $v_i$ are dependent as its first line.

The second argument says $w$ is arbitrary; in fact, it's not. It was constructed specifically in a way that depends on $v_1, \dots, v_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L:V\rightarrow W$ be injective and linear, $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ linearly independent in $V$.

**Proof:**  We need to show that $\lambda_1L(v_1)+\cdots+\lambda_nL(v_n)=0 \implies \lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_n=0$.

$\lambda_1L(v_1)+\cdots+\lambda_nL(v_n)=0 \iff L(\lambda_1 v_1+\cdots+\lambda_n v_n)=L(0)$ by the linearity of $L$.
This gives $\lambda_1v_1+\cdots+\lambda_n v_n=0$ by the injectivity of $L$. But since $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent in $V$, we have $\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_n=0$. Therefore $\lambda_1L(v_1)+\cdots+\lambda_nL(v_n)=0$ $\implies \lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_n=0$, so $\{L(v_1),\ldots,L(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent in $W$. $\square$

Let $:V\rightarrow W$ be surjective and linear, $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ spans $V$.

**Proof:** We need to show that $\{L(v_1),\ldots, L(v_n)\}$ spans $W$.

*I have no idea how to do this.... I am getting a bit frustated :(*

Comment: Please try starting the proof the way I suggested.  Then keep going, using assumptions as needed.

Comment: See the edited version of my answer for significant structural hints on part 2, in the form of "put these out-of-order sentences in correct order to complete the proof."